# SQL Server XML Update Serialized Array based on compound XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery, xquery-sql, xquery-update

I have a db table with an XmlProperties column with data in the form of a Serialized .NET array. Here's an example:

```xml
<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <Key>CompanyName</Key>
    <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:string">Company A</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringanyType>
  <KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <Key>CompanyUrl</Key>
    <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:string" />
  </KeyValueOfstringanyType>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType>
```

I would like to update all Value elements where `Key = "CompanyName"` and `Value = "Company A"` and `set Value = "Company A, LLC."` There are other Key/Value pairs in this column so that's why I need the update to only apply to that Key/Value combination.

I am able to query and get the results using this query:

```sql
WITH KeyValues
AS (SELECT
  Id,
  key_value.value('./*:Key[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [key],
  key_value.value('./*:Value[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [value]
FROM dbo.MyTable
CROSS APPLY XmlProperties.nodes('/*:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType/*:KeyValueOfstringanyType[*:Key="CompanyName" and *:Value="Company A"]') AS N (key_value))
SELECT
  *
FROM KeyValues
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to apply that same filtering logic to a .modify statement to replace "Company A" with "Company A, LLC."

I have tried something like this to no avail:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.MyTable
SET XmlProperties.modify('replace value of (/*:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType/*:KeyValueOfstringanyType/*:Value[../*:Key="CompanyName" and ../*:Value="Company A"]) with "Company A, LLC"')
```

Anybody got an elegant solution? I feel like I'm close, but just haven't cracked it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way :

```
declare @xml XML = '<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <Key>CompanyName</Key>
    <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:string">Company A</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringanyType>
  <KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <Key>CompanyUrl</Key>
    <Value xmlns:d3p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d3p1:string" />
  </KeyValueOfstringanyType>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType>'

SET @xml.modify('
  replace value of 
    (/*:ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringanyType
     /*:KeyValueOfstringanyType[*:Key="CompanyName" and *:Value="Company A"]
     /*:Value
     /text()
    )[1] 
  with "Company A, LLC"
')
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/641)**

Notice that `replace value of` requires you to limit the xpath result to *one simple type*. See that in the above example, trailing `/text()` means the xpath returns simple type `string`, and then `()[1]` limits strings being returned to only one instance.

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm! Thanks for your great answer and explanation of the details.